# Runtime error 1004 document not saved with Vba Excel 2016

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting a `Runtime error 1004 document not saved` using vba when I want to save an Excel workbook in my folder on desktop. Here are the details of my code:

```
Private Sub Save_Click()

'Popup the Window "Save As"

Application.DisplayAlerts = False


MsgBox "Do not change the default file name proposed on the next step please !"

Dim fName As Variant

Dim DName As String  ' Variable storing name of excel workbook which has to be saved

DName = UserForm.CustomerApplication.Value & " - " & UserForm.L2GType.Value

& " - " & UserForm.Title.Value & " - " & UserForm.Country.Value & "(" & 

Year(Date) & ")"

fName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=DName, _

FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.XLSX), *.XLSX", Title:="Save As")

If fName = False Then

 Exit Sub

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:=fName, FileFormat:=51

ActiveWorkbook.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you guys please help me as i am getting bug in this part of code ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:=fName, FileFormat:=51

Comment: have you tested any of the solutions provided below ? any feedback would be nice...

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing an 'End If' at the bottom of your code. The 'If fName = False Then...' part. Try the following

```
Private Sub Save_Click()

'Popup the Window "Save As"

Application.DisplayAlerts = False


MsgBox "Do not change the default file name proposed on the next step please !"

Dim fName As Variant

Dim DName As String  ' Variable storing name of excel workbook which has to be saved

DName = UserForm.CustomerApplication.Value & " - " & UserForm.L2GType.Value

& " - " & UserForm.Title.Value & " - " & UserForm.Country.Value & "(" & 

Year(Date) & ")"

fName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=DName, _

FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.XLSX), *.XLSX", Title:="Save As")

If fName = False Then

 Exit Sub

End If

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:=fName, FileFormat:=51

ActiveWorkbook.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: wilson88 Can you please explain why End if should be at end of code?

Comment: Its a multiple line syntax rule for If statements in VBA (which applies here as your 'Exit Sub' statement is on another line). 

If it was on one line, you wouldn't need to (but I always use it anyway as I prefer to write if statements in blocks as it is easier to comprehend).  more info linked :) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/752y8abs.aspx

Comment: I think your document isnt saving because it thinks that the ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:=fName, FileFormat:=51 statement is part of the If block. So therefore it will exit the sub before the document is saved...

Answer (score 0):

`fName` is a `String`, therefore you can't compare it with `False`, but with `"False"`.

Try replacing the last section of your code with the lines below:

```
fName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=DName, _
        fileFilter:="Excel Files (*.XLSX), *.XLSX", Title:="Save As")

If fName <> "False" Then
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=fName, FileFormat:=51
Else
    MsgBox "No File was selected !"
    Exit Sub
End If

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

**Note**: using `FileFormat:=51`, means `xlOpenXMLWorkbook`, an .xlsx format (without MACROs).

**However** since you want to use the `SaveAs` command with `ThisWorkbook`, which contains this code, you will get a prompt screen that asks if you want to save it as `.xslx` , which means all your code will be lost.

You can select `FileFormat:=52`, means `xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled`, an .xlsm format (**with MACROs**).

Comment: Shai Rado i changed my code as like you told but still not working give same error. i need to save excel workbook without macro enabled

Comment: Shai Rado i am using excel 2016 so is there something wrong with file format?

Comment: Shai Rado ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:=fName, FileFormat:=51

Comment: I am getting error on line :  ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:=fName, FileFormat:=51